# Displaying Umbraco Grid in Mega Menu

Tags: razor, umbraco

I want to display Umbraco Grid in Mega Menu, and I cannot use @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("") in this scenario.
I need to get it using node variable: myNode.GetProperty("menuGrid")

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use various ways of getting content from the grid. They are all described here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout/render-grid-in-template.

In my opinion, the best way would be to create custom grid view / renderer and just use it here with proper method for retrieving content e.g.

```
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml(Html, "yourGridPropertyAlias", "customgridview")
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml(Html, "yourGridPropertyAlias", "/views/othercustomgridview.cshtml")
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I don't have access to CurrentPage. The menu displays list of countries, and when you hover on country the Grid will be displayed. (Each country has its own grid)
So normally (like with every other property) I would loop through list of my countries and display Grid for each of them dynamically.Here I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Hmm where you're rendering those data? On template / view you should be able to use CurrentPage or Model.Content or at least instance the UmbracoHelper class and do this via assigned content item. If I remember correctly, you can also do this: @Html.GetGridHtml(...) and pass the model with property alias from which you want to grab grid html.

Answer (score 0):

Marcin's suggestions were helpful with finding a solution.

Just in case somebody is looking for something similar I had my INode which hasn't got access to GetGridHtml. After convertion  to typed content I regained access to that property

```
 foreach (var country in countryNode.ChildrenAsList)
                                                {
                                                    var myNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(country.Id);
                                                    var property = myNode.GetGridHtml("menuGrid");
                                                }
```